# What would you call a party where people drink a lot in Portuguese?

Tags: vocabulário

What would you call a party where people drink a lot in Portuguese?

Context:

> We went to Peter's house for a birthday party, but later it turned into a real **banger** in the early evening.

suggestion: queima, festa, farra, festinha nervosa, bebedeira

Comment: Can you give us some context or some word in English?

Comment: Sure, in English there is a word "banger", but it does not appear in most dictionaries, it is probably a college student slang.

Comment: EDIT: the word banger only appers in urban dictionaries: http://www.internetslang.com/BANGER-meaning-definition.asp
http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=banger

Comment: I nave no definitive answer but at least in some regions of Brazil "cachaçada" is an acceptable alternative. And any Brazilian would understand it for the mere fact that it has "cachaça" in the name.

Comment: Banger is exactly a word you hear all the time in English.

Answer (score 6):

I’m not aware of any Portuguese word specifically for ‘party with a lot of drinking going on’. If a phrase will do, you could use ***festa bem regada***:

> Fomos a um aniversário na casa do Peter, mas depois à noitinha aquilo deu numa **festa verdadeiramente bem regada**

[*Regar* (Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/regar) literally means ‘to water’ (plants), but it’s used informally to mean ‘to have drinks with’ (a meal, a party). Here are some examples of actual usage (my emphasis in all quotes):

> “Esta tem sido uma **festa bem regada**”, confessa-nos um dos elementos. As garrafas, numa contagem rápida, aproximam-se da meia centena. Mas duas grades ainda estão intactas.
>   [[«A volta no seu esplendor», *Correio da Manhã* (Portugal), 2005]](http://www.cmjornal.pt/desporto/imprimir/a-volta-no-seu-esplendor)
>
> Norte Americanos […] deixaram roubar um computador com programação secreta depois de uma **festa "bem regada"** na companhia de prostitutas.
>   [[Agência Angola Press, 2002]](http://www.angop.ao/angola/pt_pt/noticias/internacional/2002/9/42/,e48d0fe4-626e-453a-806f-fb5c8ea823b9.html)

There are a couple of single words that by themselves won’t imply a party, but in the right context, as in your sentence, may convey the right meaning:

> Fomos a um aniversário na casa do Peter, mas depois à noitinha aquilo deu numa verdadeira **borracheira**

[*Borracheira* (Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/borracheira) is an informal word for an action, talk, or state of a drunken person, from [*borracho* (Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/borracho), ‘drunken’. So the emphasis here is on getting drunk, and someone hearing the sentence above might get the impression that things went a little down the hill, where propriety is concerned, at the party. You could off course use [*bebedeira* (Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/bebedeira) instead. But while *bebedeira* simply means the ‘state of being drunk’, *borracheira* is broader, including silly things you do while drunk. Here’s from an [advert for the “Borracheira da Engenharia”](https://www.antecipei.com.br/borracheira-da-engenharia), a student party at Universidade Federal de Santa Maria (Rio Grande do Sul, Brazil):

> A festa contará com decoração diferenciada da Ensaio Formaturas, venda de vodka com energético e novas surpresas! Não perca!
>   “VEM PRA **BORRACHEIRA** VOCÊ TAMBÉÉM... VEM!!”
>   [image]

---

For a milder tone you could go for:

> Fomos a um aniversário na casa do Peter, mas depois à noitinha aquilo deu numa verdadeira **copofonia**

[*Copofonia* (Priberam)](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/copofonia) (seemingly not used in this sense in Brazil) is an informal word for the loud noise of people drinking or the drinking itself. It comes from [*copo* (Aulete 5)](http://www.aulete.com.br/copo), ‘drinking glass,’ and a rather common metonym for alcoholic drink. So this version of the sentence puts more emphasis on drinking and lots of noise and activity, rather than getting drunk. It looks as though this word is not used in Brazil, but it has a long tradition in Portugal. There even has been an “Associação Técnica de Copofonia”, as attested by this membership card I found in [blog *Pombalinho*](http://opombalinho.blogspot.pt/2012/10/copofonia.html):
[image]

Comment: Não acho que exista nada que realmente encaixe no significado de *banger*.

Comment: @JorgeB. Também acho que não. Isto é, numa palavra só, não.

Comment: Your answer certainly refers to what people say in pt-PT.  We don't use those terms on this side of the Atlantic.  "uma festa bem regada" might be occasionally heard in formal speech.

Comment: As for "Borracheira da Engenharia" in Rio Grande do Sul, that's certainly Spanish influence from neighbouring Uruguai.

Answer (score 0):

In pt-BR, especially in southeastern Brazil, you might call it **"uma festa rave"**  .

Depending on who organizes it, where it's held and who it going to attend it, one certain "festa rave" may have distinct characteristics from another. Certain characteristics, however, are always present:

- **DJ's**, **loud electronic music**, dancing, especially the kind that's popular with young people
- They usually take place in **smallholdings, hangars, ranches, or rented mansions**, on the outskirts of large cities. They can also take place on University Grounds. In this case, permission would have to be obtained previously from the administrative division and there would be restrictions about drugs and the students' age.
- They usually **last around 12 hours** but can go on for much longer, say, 72 hours.
- The public consists **primarily of people under 30**, males and females, usually students.
- There is always **a lot of booze and ilicit drugs** (ecstasy, cocaine, pot, etc). The latter may be used either openly or in a somewhat concealled manner.

**A smaller event**, but very popular with the college crowd, is **"uma chopada"** (from **"chope"**, which means [**draught beer or keg beer in Brazil**"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draught_beer)) where there is also a lot of booze, especially beer, tid-bits, electronic music, dancing, hard rock, etc. It's usually previously advertised on notice boards where there is also information about admission tickets. The event can take place wherever the organizers find more appropriate.

Other terms are also current usage: **"uma festinha"**, **"uma reunião"**, **"uma noitada"**, etc.

As for  **"uma farra"** it can also be used for a small event among friends, though it's a bit vague. It may include all the items I've mentioned for a rave party, plus casual sex, or just one of those items. As I've said, "uma farra" is too vague: **one man's "farra" is another man's "innocent gathering"**.

Comment: Eu pensava que uma rave era unicamente para música eletrónica - trance, etc.

Comment: @ANeves sim e é isso mesmo. Pelo que eu entendi uma *banger* é uma festa daquelas típicas que se vem nos filmes nas fraternidades universitárias com muito álcool e loucura.

Comment: Could it be "festinha nervosa"?

Comment: Rave rola bebida como outras festas, mas pessoal vai mesmo para se drogar.

Comment: new suggestion: "bebedeira"

Comment: I don't think "rave" would be a good translation. Not all raves have to have a lot of alcohol, and not all bangers are raves. They are orthogonal concepts.

Comment: @brandizzi   In addition to "rave", I've offered some other choices.

Answer (score 0):

"*Cervejada*" could be a term used in Brazil, although this is specific to beer (beer = cerveja).

It if is to drink too much in general terms, independently of the consumable alcoholic beverage, it could be called a "*bebedeira*". Notice however, this is not the name of the party in itself, yet it is a good word to describe drinking too much in a social manner.

Ex:

`A festa ontem virou uma verdadeira bebedeira. Todo mundo ficou muito bêbado.`